# Clonezilla how to change default save location

Tags: clonezilla

I've set up Clonezilla on a Ubuntu 12.04 server, and it is working beautifully, on a machine with 250 gb space. Now, I've just purchased a 2TB drive and would like to mount this drive to somewhere like /media/STORAGE and change the default save location for clonezilla from /home/partimag to somewhere on the new harddrive. How would I accomplish this?

Would it be better to have a symlink to the mounted hard drive?

Answer (score 3):

Edit **/etc/drbl/drbl.conf**

look for:
**ocsroot="/home/partimag"**

set it to
**ocsroot="/media/STORAGE"**

Comment: Outstanding what great information!!!